# Date within two date columns based on some condition in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, timestamp

I have a table in which there are two timestamp columns that represents `effective` and `expiration` dates and I need to fetch those rows where the current timestamp falls in those two date columns.

This can be done by putting condition in SQL query as follows
  `effectiveDate <= current_timestamp and current_timestamp < expirationDate`.

The issue is that the above condition is to be satisfied if `expirationDate` is not null. If it is null, then only
`effectiveDate <= current_timestamp` will be checked.

This is a sort of some dynamic SQL, i guess. I am using Hibernate in the project. i can use either critera API or HQL or SQL anything.

Please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is not quite SQL.  But what you want is something like:

```
where effectiveDate <= current_timestamp and
      (expirationDate is NULL or current_timestamp < expirationDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing dynamic about the SQL you want.  Try this:

```
Criteria c = sf.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyObject.class)
    .add(Restrictions.lt("effectiveDate",dateArgument))
    .add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.isNull("expirationDate"),
        Restrictions.gt("expirationDate",dateArgument)));
```

Calling `c.list()` will return every `MyObject` that has an `effectiveDate` less than the given date *AND* also has an `expirationDate` that is either `null` or greater than the given date.

Should give you what you want as long as you don't mind using Hibernate Criteria Queries.

**Note**: Feel free to exchange `.lt(...)` and `.gt(...)` with `.le(...)` and `.ge(...)` depending on your specific requirements.